# How to create components in a loop?

Tags: vue.js

I have a project that creates photos. I want every photo to be a vue component.

I send an axios request and after the answer I want to insert each photo one by one, but each photo must be a vue-component.

```
 axios.get('/api/prepare?query='+encodeURIComponent(this.text))
                .then(function(result){
                    const result_data = result.data;
                    self.images = result_data.images;
                        let index = 0;
                        for(let image in result_data.images){
                            new Vue({
                                el : "#photo",
                                template : "Photo.vue",
                                data : {
                                    src : result_data.images[image].src,
                                    symbolId : image,
                                    photoId : result_data.images[image].photo_id,
                                    name : index
                                }
                            });
                            index++;
                        }
```

in my template i have `<div id="photo"></div>`

but i get an error in console

> Cannot find element: #photo

Answer (score 1):

First, define a reusable component using `props` to pass data down to it:

```
<script>
    Vue.component('my-photo-component', {
        template: `<img :src="image_source"/>`,
        props: ['image_source'],
        data: function() {
            return {
                other: 'data'
            };
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then, we can use this component in a `v-for` loop:

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            photos: []
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="photo in photos">
        <my-photo-component :image_source="photo.src"></my-photo-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is obviously missing some key pieces, such as the actual data you need. You will need to expand upon this toy example in order to achieve what you want. But this should push you in the right direction.

Comment: I did as you said but now in cosole next error "did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to provide feedback without seeing updated code.