# If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead. Laravel + VueJs

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

First question - [How to create components in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828366/how-to-create-components-in-a-loop/47828602#47828602)

In my Index.vue I have a loop

```
<div v-for="(image, id, index) in images" class="col-md-4">
  <photo :src ="image.src" :symbolId="image.id" :photoId="image.photo_id" :index="index"></photo>
</div>
```

in my app.js i registered a component

```
Vue.component('photo',
   require('./components/Photo.vue')
);
```

and in my Photo.vue

```
<template>
    <img v-on:click="replaceImages()" :src="src" class="img-responsive image" :data-symbol-id="symbolId" :data-photo-id="photoId">
<input :name="index" :data-symbol-id="symbolId" :data-photo-id="photoId" 
type="hidden" :value="src">
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'photo',
    props: {
        src: {
            type : String,
            required: true
        },
        symbolId: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        photoId: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        index: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

but when npm compiling it, i get an error

> Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one `div` instead template, Vue expect one root element which contain all template, template tag is omitted by vue if using as below example

```
<template>
<div>
    <img v-on:click="replaceImages()" :src="src" class="img-responsive image" :data-symbol-id="symbolId" :data-photo-id="photoId">
<input :name="index" :data-symbol-id="symbolId" :data-photo-id="photoId" 
type="hidden" :value="src">
</div>
</template>
```

```js
var child = {
  template : '<div>Child component</div>'
}
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  components:{
    child
  },
  data:{
    name:''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<child></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But everything worked after a simple addition to the div! Without var child. http://joxi.ru/LmGakZYueXEL6A

Comment: @Виктор : Yes I said `Add one div instead template, Vue expect one root element which contain all template`

Comment: can i use span instead div ?

Comment: @Виктор : Change you title as `Getting error in vue : Component template should contain exactly one root element` To easy Identify to others

Comment: You can also [find some discussion here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/384)